# Using PyImgur's documented way to upload, uploadsrefuse to show up in gallery

Tags: python, python-3.7, imgur

I use this code from PyImgur's docs:

```
import pyimgur

CLIENT_ID = "xxx"
PATH = "image.jpg"

im = pyimgur.Imgur(CLIENT_ID)
uploaded_image = im.upload_image(PATH, title="Uploaded with PyImgur")
print(uploaded_image.title)
print(uploaded_image.link)
print(uploaded_image.size)
print(uploaded_image.type)
```

But it doesn't show up in my gallery

Comment: don't you get error message?

Comment: no. it uploads, but it doesn't show up in my gallery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is how all APIs work (not only `imgur API`).

`CLIENT_ID` gives access to API but only as anonymous user.

Program with the same `CLIENT_ID` can be used by different users (not only by you) and every user has to allow to access to his/her data.

First program has to generate special URL to `imgur.com` (I'm not sure if it need `CLIENT_SECRET` for this)

```
 im = pyimgur.Imgur(CLIENT_ID)#, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)

 auth_url = im.authorization_url('pin')
```

Next you have to open this URL in web browser and it will ask you to login to `imgur.com` and it may ask you if you allow this program to access to your data. If you allow then it will display page with unique number `pin` which you have to use in program

```
 access_token, refresh_token = im.exchange_pin(pin)
```

and then program will have access to your data and it can upload to your account - until you close program.

This also gives you `access_token` (which is like login and password in one number) which program can use to access your data after restarting program - so you don't have to login again to `imgur.com` and copy `pin`.

For security reason `access_token` expires after 60 minutes so you get also `refresh_token` (which never expire) which program has to use every 60 minutes to generate new `access_token`.

```
 im = pyimgur.Imgur(CLIENT_ID, access_token=access_token, refresh_token=refresh_token)
```

Now it will upload image to your account after restarting program.

---

Minimal working code.

I use `try/except` to load `access_token`, `refresh_token` from file or open web page for `pin` to generate `access_token`, `refresh_token`. This method I saw in some example for Google API (but it was using `pickle` to keep tokens in file).

```
import pyimgur
import webbrowser

CLIENT_ID = "123456789012345"
#CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxyyyzzz'

# access to user data

try:
    # try to loading access_token, refresh_token from file
    with open('tokens.txt') as f:
        access_token, refresh_token = f.read().strip().split()
        
    # run with access_token, refresh_token    
    im = pyimgur.Imgur(CLIENT_ID, access_token=access_token, refresh_token=refresh_token)
    
except FileNotFoundError as ex:
    # ask for new access_token, refresh_token when file doesn't exists
    
    # run without access_token, refresh_token
    im = pyimgur.Imgur(CLIENT_ID)  #, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)

    # generate url
    auth_url = im.authorization_url('pin')
    
    # open url in web browser
    webbrowser.open(auth_url)
    
    # ask for `pin` from web page
    pin = input("What is the pin? ")
    
    # get access_token, refresh_token
    access_token, refresh_token = im.exchange_pin(pin)

    # save access_token, refresh_token in file
    with open('tokens.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(f'{access_token} {refresh_token}')

# upload image

PATH = "lenna.png"

uploaded_image = im.upload_image(PATH, title="Uploaded with PyImgur")

print('[upload] title:', uploaded_image.title)
print('[upload] link :', uploaded_image.link)
print('[upload] size :', uploaded_image.size)
print('[upload] type :', uploaded_image.type)

# share with community - to see image (as post) on imgur's main page 
uploaded_image.submit_to_gallery(title='Shared with PyImgur')
```

---

This add image to user account but I couldn't add to selected album. There is `upload_image(..., album=...)` but it needs album's ID, not its name. Using `im.search_gallery(query)` I could even get album's ID but I always get error that I can't change information in album which is in gallery.

---

**EDIT:**

This code adds image to your account and you can get its link and send this link to other people in mail, messanger or put link on some forum, or use it to display image on your own web page

... but this not send it on main page of Imgur - it doesn't `"share to community"`.

You have to add

```
uploaded_image.submit_to_gallery(title='Title of your post')
```

And then people can see it on [Imgur's main page](https://imgur.com/) and vote it.

I added this line to code above.

PyImgur source code: [Image.submit_to_gallery()](https://github.com/Damgaard/PyImgur/blob/master/pyimgur/__init__.py#L611), [Album.submit_to_gallery()](https://github.com/Damgaard/PyImgur/blob/master/pyimgur/__init__.py#L325)

---

When you allow your program to access your data then you should see your program in `Apps Used` and you can use `revoke access` to disallow program to access your data

I use `Client ID` for my application `furas-imgur` so after allowing to access my data I see `furas-imgur` in `Apps Used`

[image]

Comment: do you know how to make it post publicly?

Comment: do you know by chance know how to post it publicly?

Comment: @diogenesjunior uploaded image is public - you can get link to image and send it in mail, messanger or put on forum (or use to insert image on your own page). But if you means `"share to community"` to display it as post on Imgur's main page (so people can vote it) then you have to use `uploaded_image.submit_to_gallery(title='Title of your post')`. I added it to code in answer.